# How to get the results of ls piped to wc when running inside of a for loop?

Tags: linux, wc

So I am trying to make this a single command instead of having to dump the data to a file and then cat the file and pipe the output to wc -l.  The whole line of code looks like this:

```
for file in `grep Rawdata freeze2-1.out | awk '{print $6}'`
 do
  ls -1 /appdata/frozen_files/$file | wc -l
 done
```

But the output gives me a count for every line instead of a total for the entire output.  Is there anyway this can be done where I get the output of a single number for all of the files or do I have to redirect to a file and make another step?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please indicate it by clicking the checkmark next to it; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to count the total number of files in a directory named by field 6 in the freeze2-1.out file, but only where "Rawdata" appears somewhere on that line of that file.

The main error in your initial post was simply one of logic or placement; you were asking `wc -l` to count the individual lines *inside* the loop inside of asking it for the total number of lines that the overall loop provided. That's what most of the existing answers are correcting.

I made up a sample freeze2-1.out file so that I could "play along at home"; here's what I put in it:

```
Rawdata 2 3 4 5 file1
Rawdata 2 3 4 5 file2
Rawdata 2 3 4 5 file3
```

I also populated a *relative* directory named "appdata/frozen_files" with directory names based on field 6 above. Note that your actual path is an *absolute* path starting with /appdata/frozen_files. I've placed 1 file in file1, 2 files in file2, and 3 files in file3, for a total of 6 files.

The first improvement that I'll suggest is to combine the `grep` and the `awk`, since awk can do pattern matching. [RomanPerekhrest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398559/117549) did this in their answer as well:

```
awk '/Rawdata/ { print $6 }' freeze2-1.out
```

The sample output is then:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I'll point out here that since awk splits fields based on spaces, tabs, and newlines, printing specifically field 6 implies that each line of output will have a word with no spaces in it.

There are a few ways to count the number of files in a directory. Using `ls -1 | wc -l` is *a* way, but it fails in a very particular case where a filename has an embedded newline; you could create such a file manually with `touch $'file\nname'`. Since awk is reading lines of input delimited by newlines, we won't hit that special case here, but I wanted to mention it. For example:

```
# create the file
$ touch $'file\nname'

# check the listing; looks okay so far
$ ls -1
appdata
file?name
freeze2-1.out

# count them up
$ ls -1 | wc -l
4 

# woops! should be 3!
```

For that reason, I'll demonstrate two other methods to count the files in a directory.

The first method uses the `set` builtin to take its arguments and convert them into positional arguments named by $1, $2, $3, etc.

```
$ sum=0
$ for file in $(awk '/Rawdata/ { print $6 }' freeze2-1.out)
  do
    set -- "appdata/frozen_files/${file}/"*
    sum=$((sum + $#))
  done
$ echo "$sum"
6
```

This initializes a counter `sum` to zero, then loops through the filenames from the awk output. It calls `set` with the quoted path to the directory, followed by the `*` shell glob, which expands to all of the (non-hidden) files in that directory. That matches the `ls -1` behavior of excluding hidden files (those starting with a period). The number of parameters is given by the special variable `$#`, which we add within the loop to `sum`, then print it at the end.

A second method, for shells that support arrays, is to put the globbed filenames into an array, then count the elements of the array:

```
$ sum=0
$ for file in $(awk '/Rawdata/ { print $6 }' freeze2-1.out )
  do
    n=("appdata/frozen_files/${file}"/*)
    sum=$((sum + ${#n[@]}))
  done
$ echo "$sum"
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the word count to the end;

```
for file in $(grep Rawdata freeze2-1.out | awk '{print $6}')
 do
  ls -1 /appdata/frozen_files/$file
 done | wc -l
```

or sum it;

```
C=0
for file in $(grep Rawdata freeze2-1.out | awk '{print $6}')
 do
  C=$[$C+$(ls -1 /appdata/frozen_files/$file | wc -l)]
 done
echo $C;
```

or maybe use find if your file structure can match a pattern (or regex)

```
find /appdata/frozen_files/ -iname '*.raw' |wc -l
```

Comment: Snippet-only solutions don't look very good, it is better if you also explain what are you doing and how.